# Sidebar with expanding part

Tags: semantic-ui

I am new to semantic UI (and web development in general) and am looking to implement a design like this:

[image: Menu mockup]

So to be clear: The bar with icons is always there, the labels for the icons appear only when the mouse is over the menu bar somewhere; label rectangle hoovers over the site content and it does not stretch from top to bottom.

Can anyone give me a tip on how to accomplish this?

Menu/icon bar can be a sidebar that is always visible I guess:

```
<div class="ui visible left thin sidebar borderless vertical icon menu">
  <a class="item">
    <i class="search icon"></i>
    // Would like label text here 
  </a>
  ..etc
</div>
```

But I don't see anything that can help me with the labels/popup and preferably have the definition of that text in the same item.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try to add the menu item with the text like a normal menu with icons and text. Than set `overflow: hidden` to the parent side bare and make it only as wide as you want the thin bar to be. On hover you'll make it wider. I know of now way to do this only in Semantic UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nice as Semantic UI is, we now decided that it not the right framework for us. We are building an technical application, not a regular website, which is all custom design and we would run into issues like this all the time. @Michael: thanks for answering!